# Switching windows with non angular pages using Webdriver JS

Tags: selenium-webdriver, javascript, protractor

I have a non angular page that I open and then click a link, which changes pages and I fill out a form with some information and then click a button. Upon clicking that button another browser window is loaded. I need to switch over to the newly open page and work with some elements on that page and then return to the first window (the main page). I have the following code below:

```
    describe('Test', function () {
    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
    });

    it('Do authentication of session', function () {
        session.goToCommandPage().then(function () {
            browser.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(12000);
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.findElement(by.cssContainingText('#content > span:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(5) > a', 'AuthenticateUser'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.click();
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the AuthenticateUser link to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.sendKeys(COMPANY_ID);
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the Company ID field to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.sendKeys('user');
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the User field to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                    .then(function (elem) {
                        elem.click();
                        return true;
                    });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for the Invoke button to load');
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(18000);
        }).then(function () {
            browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

                    if (handles.length > 1) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }, 12000, 'Waited for window count to be greater than 1');
        });
    });

    it('Switch to the results tab', function () {
        browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
            if (handles.length > 1) {
                handles.forEach(function (wndw) {
                    browser.driver.switchTo().window(wndw).then(function () {
                        browser.driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(7000);
                    }).then(function () {
                        browser.driver.getTitle().then(function (title) {
                            console.log('Title now: ' + title);
                            if(title == 'localhost/Service/WebService.asmx/AuthenticateUser') {
                                browser.driver.wait(function () {
                                    return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.collapsible .expanded .text'))
                                        .then(function (elem) {
                                            elem.getText().then(function (textProduced) {
                                                console.log('Text printed: ' + textProduced);
                                            });
                                            return true;
                                        });
                                }, 12000, 'Waited for the output text to load');
                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
            }

            browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]).then(function () {
                browser.driver.wait(function () {
                    return browser.driver.findElement(by.css('#content > span > form > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2) > input'))
                }, 12000, 'Waited for the Company ID field to load');
            })
        });
    });
});
```

I use the various browser.driver.wait's because I wanted to make sure I was waiting for the element to be present before interacting with it. I also use browser.driver.findElement actions instead of browser.findElement because they are non-angular pages.

The output looks like this:

```
Title now: WebService Web Service
```

But then I get the following error:

> ScriptTimeoutError: timeout: Timed out receiving message from
>   renderer: 10.000   (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)   (Driver
>   info: chromedriver=2.19.346078
>   (6f1f0cde889532d48ce8242342d0b84f94b114a1),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information) Command duration or timeout: 17.02 seconds"

I thought maybe it was because the new window wasn't ready to be interacted with but I check to see that their are more than 1 window open before going on to the second it. I see both tabs loaded before it fails but it stays on the first tab. I am writing this using Protractor using JavaScript because I usually interact with angular pages, and will in future test, but I need to do these actions first.

---

EDIT: I tried the below code, but still got:

> Failed: timeout: Timed out receiving message from renderer: 10.000
>         (Session info: chrome=49.0.2623.110)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=2.21.371459 (36d3d07f660ff2bc1bf28a75d1cdabed0983e7c4),platform=Windows NT 6.1 SP1
>   x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace
>   information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 22.02 seconds
>       Build info: version: '2.52.0', revision: '4c2593c', time: '2016-02-11 19:06:42'

```
browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {
    var popUpHandle = handles[1];
    browser.driver.switchTo().window(popUpHandle).then(function (handle) {
        browser.sleep(12000);
        handle = browser.driver.getWindowHandle();
        expect(handle).toEqual(popUpHandle);
        browser.driver.executeScript('window.focus();');
    })
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to turn `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true` on when you are accessing a non-angular page.

If It's pop up then, 
just as information for other possible users, I modified a bit the promise handle:

```
var handles = handlePromise.then(function (handles) {
    popUpHandle = handles[1];
    var handle = browser.switchTo().window(popUpHandle);
    handle = browser.getWindowHandle();
    expect(handle).toEqual(popUpHandle);
    browser.driver.executeScript('window.focus();');
});
```

And it worked beautifully. After this point I could send the data to the inputs in the window and do whatever I wanted with it. Pretty.

You may check this site-
http://engineering.wingify.com/posts/angularapp-e2e-testing-with-protractor/

Comment: I have browser.ignoreSyncronization = true in a beforeEach (see above). Do you think I should move it elsewhere? Both the starting page and new page are non-angular. Also, would handlePromise in the code you be  browser.driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles { ?

Answer (score 0):

> browser.ignoreSynchronisation is deprecated now.

For switching between  Angular & Non-angular pages ,[Use waitForAngularEnabled().](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBrowser.prototype.waitForAngularEnabled)

If set to false, Protractor will not wait for Angular $http and $timeout tasks to complete before interacting with the browser. This can cause flaky tests, but should be used if, for instance, your app continuously polls an API with $timeout.

Call waitForAngularEnabled() without passing a value to read the current state without changing it.